# How to Convert int into char string

Tags: c, char

How can I convert numbers that are combined with - into a string.

For example: `12-4-30`

I need to make all those numbers including the - into one string.

I tried:

```
string 12-4-30;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you mean into a string?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? And `12-4-30` is not *a* number, it's a series of three numbers divided by dashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What?

A character is typically just that, *one* character. Not seven.

You can do a wide character:

```
char what = '12-4-30';
```

but I think that's more bits than most compilers will let you have in a `char`, so it's not going to work.

If you meant a string of character, you should use `snprintf()`:

```
char what[32];

snprintf(what, sizeof what, "%d-%d-%d", 12, 4, 30);
printf("built string: '%s'\n", what);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A char by definition stores one character.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you said character but character reads only one letter...so you have to declare char array as

```
char say[32];
```

Then use `sprintf` to display string

```
snprintf(what, sizeof say, "%d-%d-%d", 12, 4, 30);
printf("built string: '%s'\n", say);
```